# How can show bottom navigation view at a top of the app?

Tags: java, android

I want to show the bottom navigation view at the top of my app like facebook, i try this but its not showing anything.

[image]

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. Also, please create a [mcve]

Comment: Thats probably a `TabLayout`..

Comment: you could just create horizontal linear layout with 4 buttons and switch the view according to the button, Using fragments is the best option by my opinion

Comment: Thanks sir but i want add activities not faragment and this is not posible whith tab layout

Answer (score 0):

Use `TabLayout` and you will have something like that.
Here below is a video which I think it will help you.
You need to use `Fragments` and `TabLayout`

https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/tab-layout-with-fragments

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where the bottom navigation view is placed, you can just place it at top of your layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```